# How can I get moment to display "yesterday" and not "a day ago"?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have the following code, which is used to find the humanized time difference between two dates, the problem is that I don't want to have 'a day ago', but show 'yesterday'.

```js
function humanize(date) {
  const then = moment.utc(date); 
  
  return then.fromNow();
}

function getYesterdayAsISO() {
    var date = new Date();
    date.setDate(date.getDate()-1);
    return date.toISOString();
}

console.log(humanize(getYesterdayAsISO()));
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: check again in my console it shows me "a day ago"

Comment: `then.fromNow()` is a duration and has no notion of what day it was/is about.  Perhaps https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/calendar-time/ is something close enough?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are found in translation files. You can change them in the [`relativeTime` in `en-gb.js` at Line 42](https://github.com/moment/moment/blob/develop/locale/en-gb.js#L42):

```
d : 'yesterday',
```

But this still shows as `yesterday ago`. The right one you can change is the `past`

```
past : '%s ago',
```

Also, without changing the source, I added the following by injecting:

```
moment.updateLocale('en-gb', {
  relativeTime: {
    past : '%s',
    d : 'yesterday'
  }
});
```

The above may not work in all the cases, and it should be specifically used only for your current project.

I get the following in the console:

[image]

**Working Example**

```js
moment.updateLocale('en-gb', {
  relativeTime: {
    past : '%s',
    d : 'yesterday'
  }
});

function humanize(date) {
  const then = moment.utc(date); 

  return then.fromNow();
}

function getYesterdayAsISO() {
  var date = new Date();
  date.setDate(date.getDate()-1);
  return date.toISOString();
}

console.log(humanize(getYesterdayAsISO()));
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Have you seen the deprecation warning on that code?

Comment: @Liam Oops, I didn't see it. Where was it?

Comment: @Liam Thanks mate! Updated... `:)`

Answer (score 1):

```
moment.updateLocale("en-gb", {
  relativeTime: {
    future: "in %s",
    past: "%s",
    s: "a few seconds ago",
    ss: "%d seconds ago",
    m: "a minute ago",
    mm: "%d minutes ago",
    h: "an hour ago",
    hh: "%d hours ago",
    d: "yesterday",
    dd: "%d days ago",
    M: "a month ago",
    MM: "%d months ago",
    y: "a year ago",
    yy: "%d years ago",
  },
});
```

this is stupid code but it resolved my issue